# Time complexity and its formula

Tags: polynomials

Is there any example support the case of $O(n^k)$
where $k$ has a fixed calculated value for every $n$ and $k$ is not a constant value for all $n$.
As $k$ depends on the value of $n$ in polynomial representation.

Also, I wonder, what is its type of time complexity?

Comment: It just seems like a roundabout way of saying that $k$ is a function of $n$? If so, then just write that function. E.g. say $k = 2n$, then $O(n^{2n})$.

Answer (score 1):

The highest degree of polynomial is represented in sequence :
(n^-3* n^n, n^-2*n^n, n^-1*n^n, n^0 *n^n, n^1*n^n, n^2 *n^n, n^5*n^n, n^7 *n^n,... etc), where k is the exponent.

K is variable odd increasing function depends on the value of n which is
K = 1,3,5,7,9.. etc
for (n=4,5,6,7,.. etc) respectively.